# Add Redis to a NestJS config ConfigMap?

Tags: kubernetes, redis, configmap

I was given a Redis url and port.  I have an existing deployment ConfigMap, I'm not sure where/how to add the Redis information to the map.

I was given a general example, but not sure where to plug it in. I *think* it would in the container section, but I'm not positive.

```
- name: redis
        image: redis:latest  
        ports:
        - containerPort: xxxx
        resources: {}
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: __APP__-__ENV__
  name: __APP__-__ENV__
  namespace: __PROJECT__
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: __APP__-__ENV__
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: __APP__-__ENV__
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: __REGISTRY__/__APP__:__TAG__
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: __APP__
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        env:
        - name: APP
          value: __APP__
        - name: ENV
          value: __ENV__
        envFrom: 
        - secretRef:
            name: __APP__-__ENV__
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 3000
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 20
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Comment: That's highly dependent on your specific application, and how (and if) the ConfigMap data is used.  If you weren't in a cluster environment, how would you use the Redis configuration information?  The fragment you show looks like a container definition in a Pod specification; you'd use that to run your own in-cluster Redis, probably in a separate Deployment with a separate Service, but that wouldn't use the location information you'd been given.

Comment: Thanks, makes me feel better as it was dropped in my lap without further context and it's outside mywheelhouse

Comment: little more context, I'll be connecting to an already provisioned cluster